# What is the proper way to operate on interpolating functions?

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I am trying to multiply an interpolating function by -1.  If I do this Mathematica does not seem to allow any further operations.  Bear with me while I generate the Interpolating Function in question.  It is a derivative of the output of NDSolve.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Remove["Global`*"];
center = Rectangle[{-.1, -.1}, {.1, .1}];
shield = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
reg = RegionDifference[shield, center];
uif = NDSolveValue[{\!\(
    \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[x, y]\)\) == 0,
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 >= .5],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x^2 + y^2 < .5]},u, {x, y} \[Element] reg]

partialx = Derivative[1, 0][uif];
NIntegrate[partialx[.5, y], {y, -.5, .5}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
Plot[partialx[x, -.5], {x, -1, 1}]
```

At this point everything is fine.  NIntegrate and Plot work.

However, this code does not work.

```
partialxneg = -1*Derivative[1, 0][uif];
NIntegrate[partialxneg[.5, y], {y, -.5, .5}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
Plot[partialxneg[x, -.5], {x, -1, 1}]
```

NIntegrate fails with

> The integrand (-InterpolatingFunction[{{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}, {4, 4225, 0, {1320, 0}, {3, 3}, {1 ,0}, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False}, {NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh[{{-1., -1.}, {-1., -0.875}, <<47>>, {0.875, -1.}, <<1270>>}, <<2>>, {<<24>>[{{<<1>>}, <<49>>, <<94>>}]}]}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., <<1270>>}, {Automatic}])[<<1>>] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-0.5, 0.5}}. >>

Also, Plot does not plot anything.

All I did was multiply the derivative by -1.

Comment: As a side note you can use `Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}` to get a better resolution of the `NDSolve` result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with interpolating functions per se; it arises from the way *Mathematica* deals with functional expressions in general. Consider,

```
f = #^2 &; g = -1 f; h = (-1 #)& @* f; hx[x_] = -1 f[x];
{f[2], g[2], h[2], hx[2]}
```

> ```
> {4, (-(#1^2 &))[2], -4, -4}
> ```

*Mathematica* simply doesn't recognize `g` as a function, but `h`, which is based on the composition of functions works fine. ( `@*` is the operator form of [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Composition.html)).

Therefore, you could use

```
partialxneg = -1 # & @* Derivative[1, 0][uif]
```

or

```
partialxneg[x_, y_] = -1 (Derivative[1, 0][uif])[x, y]
```

With either of these definitions, you will get

```
Plot[partialxneg[x, -.5], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

But that's kind of silly when

```
Plot[-partialx[x, -.5], {x, -1, 1}]
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to times -1 to the InterpolatingFunction. Using the `FullForm`, you'll see the structure will change to `Times[-1,InterpolatingFunction[...]]`. So it's pointless for *Mathematica* to do the integral and the plot.

Instead, you can use the -1 in the `NIntegrate` and `Plot` directly.

```
NIntegrate[-partialx[.5, y], {y, -.5, .5}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
Plot[-partialx[x, -.5], {x, -1, 1}]

(*==> 0.716431 and the upsidedown plot*)
```