# Derivative of Vectoral NDSolve Interpolated Function / Rule Solutions,/., and Vector NDSolve

Tags: replacement, interpolation, implementation-details

I need to find the instantaneous phase and instantaneous frequency for a rotating system. I am having difficulty making the math work with interpolating functions.

First, here is a problem without interpolating functions that I can make work:

```
phase[t_] := ArcTan[Cos[2*t + .1 t^2], Sin[2*t + .1 t^2]]
Plot[phase[t], {t, 0, 20}]
frequency = D[phase[t], t];
Plot[frequency, {t, 0, 20}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: phase vs t]
[image: freq vs time]

In this first example, Mathematica is able to take the derivative of the phase to yield frequency. Now, in 3 dimensions with the Bloch equation:

```
eqn = {m'[t] == -2*Cross[m[t], {0, 0, 1}], m[0] == {1, 0, 0}}; 
sol1 = NDSolve[eqn, {m}, {t, 0, 20}]  ;
mm[t_] := m[t] /. sol1[[1]];

phase[t_] := ArcTan[First[mm[t]], Last[Most[mm[t]]]];
Plot[phase[t], {t, 0, 20}]
freq[t_] := D[ArcTan[First[mm[t]], Last[Most[mm[t]]]], t];
Plot[freq[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

This phase plot looks about the same as the first example. So why can't Mathematica take the derivative?  Here is the error Mathematica spits out:

```
General::ivar: 0.0004085714285714286` is not a valid variable. >>
General::ivar: 0.4085718367346939` is not a valid variable. >>
General::ivar: 0.8167351020408163` is not a valid variable. >>
General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

I believe [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56540/what-is-the-proper-way-to-operate-on-interpolating-functions) question might be similar, and [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheRepresentationOfDerivatives.html) and [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApproximateFunctionsAndInterpolation.html) both provided a lot of insight, but I've tried every variation I can think of, and can't figure out how to pass this through the derivative.

What to do next? Is it just my getting caught on the notation?

---

**Edit:** Original Question About Interpolating Functions Contained Set-Delay Errors; Expanding Question to Focus on Interpolated Function.

With this code, there are no errors. However, there is also no output:

```
eqn = {m'[t] == -2*Cross[m[t], {0, 0, 1}], m[0] == {1, 0, 0}}; 
sol1 = NDSolve[eqn, {m}, {t, 0, 20}]  ;
mm = m /. sol1[[1]];

phase = ArcTan[First[mm], Last[Most[mm]]]
Plot[phase, {t, 0, 20}]
freq = D[ArcTan[First[mm]], Last[Most[mm]], t];
Plot[freq, {t, 0, 20}]
```

It is as though nothing happens. The plot thickens when I execute the next code; it shows that Mathematica can perform the the `First` of the `mm` and also the derivative of `mm`. However, with this arrangement it can't perform `ArcTan`.

```
eqn = {m'[t] == -2*Cross[m[t], {0, 0, 1}], m[0] == {1, 0, 0}}; 
sol1 = NDSolve[eqn, {m}, {t, 0, 20}]  ;
mm[t_] = m[t] /. sol1[[1]];

Plot[First[mm[t]], {t, 0, 20}] (*This Plot Works*)
dmm = D[mm[t], t];
Plot[First[dmm], {t, 0, 20}](*This Plot Works*)

phase = ArcTan[First[mm[t]], Last[Most[mm[t]]]]

Last::nolast: InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},{4,3,1,{329},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic},
{{0.,<<49>>,<<279>>}},{{{1.,0.,0.},{0.,2.,0.}},{{1.,0.000177626,0.},
{-0.000355252,2.,0.}},<<47>>,{{-0.972807,0.231619,0.},{-0.463238,-1.94561,0.}},
<<279>>},{Automatic}][] has a length of zero and no last element. >>
```

So my troubleshooting tells me that it **is** possible to take first of an interpolated function, and it is also possible to take the derivative of the interpolated function, but when it encounters them together inside the ArcTan, it isn't able to correctly call the correct direction of the interpolating function vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around I can think out:

```
Clear[a, b]
eqn = {m'[t] == -2 Cross[m[t], {0, 0, 1}], m[0] == {1, 0, 0}};
sol1 = NDSolve[eqn, {m}, {t, 0, 20}];

mm = m /. sol1[[1]];
m1 = mm /. {a_, b_, c_} -> a;
m2 = mm /. {a_, b_, c_} -> b;

freq[t_] = D[ArcTan[m1[t], m2[t]], t];

Plot[freq[t], {t, 0, 20}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

If you have difficulty in understanding, check the `InputForm` of `mm`. Also, you may be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043/1871) post.

Comment: This makes a ton of sense - obvious now that I examine it. This was my problem all along. Unfortunately [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html) link doesn't cover substitution rules for vectoral interpolating functions. In retrospect, however, it is obvious. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is a duplicate but my search terms are not on target.  The problem has nothing to do with `NDSolve`.

```
freq[t_] := D[Exp[t], t];
Plot[freq[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

> General::ivar: 0.0004085714285714286` is not a valid variable. >>
>
> General::ivar: 0.4085718367346939` is not a valid variable. >>
>
> General::ivar: 0.8167351020408163` is not a valid variable. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

These occur because `freq[0.0004085714285714286`]` evaluates to

```
D[Exp[0.0004085714285714286`], 0.0004085714285714286`]
```

and one cannot take the derivative with respect to `` 0.0004085714285714286` ``.

There are various workarounds.  Here's another

```
freq[t0_] := D[Exp[\[FormalT]], \[FormalT]] /. \[FormalT] -> t0;
```

Comment: Where does the 0.0004085714285714286 come from? Where can I read about this?

Comment: @axsvl77 It is the first number that `Plot` plugs into `freq[t]`.  If you search the site, you should be able to find related posts.  Ignore the fact that I was unsuccessful at finding them.  It's common issue with `D`, which I've seen several times on the site.

Comment: @axsvl77 Found it: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this

Comment: Well, I'm afraid this doesn't solve OP's problem. The true reason is that the `mm` outputs a list while it is **one** `InterpolatingFunction`, so list manipulations like `First`, `Most` etc. won't work anymore!

Comment: @xzczd I did not notice that part.  I would say, however, that the true reason is for the `General::ivar` messages cited is what I point out.  But solving it still leave the problem you point out.

Comment: This is a great conversation. I will learn from it and change my question.

Comment: @axsvl77 You might ask another question about how to take the derivative of the parts of a vector-valued interpolation function (without involving `Plot` in the question).  It's interesting and not obvious how to do it.  xzczd's could repost the answer and the issue would have a clean Q&A to address.

Comment: ....Unless it's been asked and answered before, too.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have extended my question to be more focused on the primary problem.  After a search, I didn't find another question about substitution, and vectoral interpolating functions.  Would it be better for me to repost a shorter, more focused question? And delete this one?

Comment: @axsvl77 I would suggest posting a new one. You might mention and link to this this, but point out the focus on the distinct issue of differentiating parts of vectorial interpolating functions. I would not recommend deleting this one.  The community seems to think duplicates help users searching for solutions.  For instance, if someone else has a similar problem using `NDSolve`, they're likely to find this question before the linked duplicate.

Comment: Ok. I like the interactive process of keeping this website focused and functional. Thanks for keeping everything straight!